# How can I make my android UI responsive for different Android screen sizes?

Tags: android, responsive

I am using **dp** as a unit of measurement for specifying sizes of my textViews, buttons, widgets, however, it messes up the whole layout when I open the application on different phones with different screen sizes. How do I make use of "percentage" sizing in Android as done in CSS, so that the application adjusts itself for different screen sizes. p.s. I am using Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The best way to make your app ui responsive is to use ConstraintLayout as the base layout in your UI.** As it allows you to specify the exact position and size for each view with respect to other views in the UI.
You can follow below link for better understanding:-
[ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)